# Making Hierarchy "less strong" in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, route

I want to know a way where the Hierarchy in my network analyst doesn't influence that much.

What happens is that when making shortest route it makes a 25-mile route, with the hierarchy it chooses to make a 40-mile route, choosing a principal road that goes a lot further than I need.

How can I make my Hierarchy more customizable, so it picks the better roads but without making so larger routes?

Comment: What are your hierarchy values, and what are they on those two roads?

Answer (score 2):

[Cost](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/understanding-network-attributes.htm#GUID-ADE9DCEB-62A0-405E-AE57-A13829DE7DEC) in Network Analysis is a way to set costs for each hierarchy level of segments. If you want to learn how to use cost in a network practically, follow the [Network Analyst Tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/about-the-network-analyst-tutorial-exercises.htm). Download tutorial data. An example of what you want can be found in "Workflow" folder,"OfficeBuilding" geodatabase. In this geodatabase:

- Open Transportation dataset.
- Double click to the Transportation_ND. Go to the Attribute tab.

[image]

- In the Attribute tab double click "WalkTime" (Walk time is a sample of cost in Network).
- In the "Evaluators" window double click to the "FloorTransitions".

[image]

Ok.You need to use script to cost each of levels. Suppose your Hierarchy field name is "Type" and "1" means "Highways".

```
If [Type] = 1 Then
    N = 1 
If .... Then 
   N = ...

   result = N+5
```

**Simple solution of using cost:**

1. Create a new Field in the network, named **HiCost** (Feel free to name this field).
2. Calculate the costs of each hierarchy level in the field. ex: set 5 for all highways. 3 for all mainstreets and ... .
3. Create a Cost with **Integer** data type then set this field for it.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28mvqOfO-dE) can be help you for the simple solution.

Note: Be sure your network one-way and directions are correct. They are very important.

Comment: wouldnt it be if [type] == 1 then....

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the Hierarchy doesnt work out the way is expected. So, a way I found it was just create restrictions. Where the Primary roads where "prefer High" restriction, Secondary Roads where "Prefer Medium" and son on.
It worked really well.